# Stop android scrollview prevent parent LinearLayout onclick

Tags: java, android, android-scrollview

I need to allow user to **CLICK** anywhere on the screen, so I've implemented onClick listener for mainLayout and it worked great.

But the problem is I've got to add a scrollview inside mainLayout to support small screen sizes and after adding scrollview, it blocks the parentLayout (in my case mainLayout) **CLICK EVENT**.

Just to exaplin this, a sample layout is as follows.

```
<!-- MAIN LAYOUT WHERE I NEED 
     THE CLICK EVENT-->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#bebebe"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:onClick="onClick_MainLayout">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/mainScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:text="TEST BUTTON 1"
                android:onClick="onClick_Button1"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:text="TEST BUTTON 2"
                android:onClick="onClick_Button2"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="My Text View"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I searched for this and found various ideas like disableing onClick manually in all other views inside scrollview etc but non of them works.

NOTE: I tried both implementing onClick listener manually in java and adding  *android:onClick="onClick_MainLayout"* in to layout. Both the same.

**EDITS ----------------------**

All the changes I've done as you (@IntelliJ Amiya) mentioned is as below. Please let me know anything is missing.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#bebebe">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/mainScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:text="TEST BUTTON 1"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:text="TEST BUTTON 2"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview1"
                android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="My Text View"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And in on create

```
    findViewById(R.id.mainLayout).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Log.v("MyLogs", "Click Event Fires...");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Could you show your full java code please.

Comment: Please check the Edits section in my question. That has full code. I've tried using android:onClick="onClick_MainLayout" attribute and writing public void onClick_MainLayout(View v) method as well as removing android:onClick="onClick_MainLayout" attribute and manually implementing onClick listener as shown in Edits section. Thanks

Comment: No need for `findViewById(R.id.mainLayout).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()`

Comment: Yes tried that... How ever you implement the Click even event is NOT the problem here (wheather using attribute or purely by java). Basically they both do the same and that's not the problem.  Basically the area that covers by Scrollview prevent parent layout click event. If I remove scrollview the OnClick fires. THANKS

Comment: Is click event of the parent RelativeLayout fires if click within the area that covers by scrollview. I saw many places discussed this prob but havent seen a solution in those,. That's why was looking to see if anyone figured out a way. If your code works could you please share all incl UI and Java bits in your question. Thanks

Comment: Kindly check my answer

Comment: @IntelliJ Amiya, Your code in your answer is NOT working.  When I comment ScrollView then click fires but NOT with that. The device I was testing was Android 4.4 tablet. Just to make sure if the old OS, installed on an Android 8 and still the same. Thanks anyway

Comment: add `android:clickable="true"` in Button section.

Comment: DONE. NOT WORKING

Answer (score 0):

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#bebebe"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/mainScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:text="TEST BUTTON 1"
                android:onClick="onClick_Button1"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:text="TEST BUTTON 2"
                android:onClick="onClick_Button2"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="My Text View"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**JAVA**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    public void onClick_Button1(View v)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "1ST Button Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    public void onClick_Button2(View v)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "2ND Button Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


}
```

Comment: Ya I tried that as well. NOT working. Did you try that and work for you? I mean adding android:duplicateParentState for ScrollView

Comment: @JibW `I mean adding android:duplicateParentState for ScrollView`-YES. For SAFE approach, You should use `RelativeLayout `.

Comment: Thank you @IntelliJ Amiya. As you mention just added android:focusable="false" / android:clickable="false" / android:duplicateParentState="true" atributes for Scrollview and then further changed all layouts as RelativeLayouts. But still the same.

Comment: @JibW if you use `RelativeLayout` then remove `android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:clickable="false"`

Comment: @JibW you should remove `android:onClick="onClick_MainLayout"` .

Comment: Ya, I tried removing android:onClick="onClick_MainLayout" and instead implementing onClick in Java code as well. I've mentioned that under NOTES in my question. Is it working like that in yours?

Comment: I've removed onClick attribute from all the buttons and just left only in mainLayout. Still it's the same... Then removed onClick attribute in that as well and implemted in java. Non of them works. Looks like scrollview blocks parent Layout's onClick wheather it is LinearLayout or RelativeLayout.

Comment: @JibW wait. Trying here.

Comment: @JibW here works fine. Just remove `android:onClick="onClick_MainLayout"`

Comment: That's strange, it's not working in mine. I will add edits section in my question that has everything I've done as you said. Please tell me if anything is different than what you have done. Thanks

Comment: @JibW Solved this yet?

Answer (score 0):

Your Scroll view overlaps the linear layout i.e @mainLayout,so
set its height to wrap content
then you can perform onclick for both scroll view buttons and mainlayout.
Pls tell me if i wrong.

```
 <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/mainScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

Comment: No it is not even when I make ScrollView to wrap_content. My layout within ScrollView has more controlls and it's taking full height even when it's wrap_content. Basically the problem is the area that cover by ScrollView makes onClick event of the Parent Layout not working wheather the Parent layout is LinearLayout or RelativeLayout. I want to allow user to click anywhere on the screen including the area that covers by ScrollView. That's why it is set for parent layout of all